# Apache Rewrite Condition After Upgrade

Tags: apache, url-rewriting, webserver, redirect, http-status-code-301

We recently upgraded a system and have noticed that our URLs have changed. I would like to configure our Apache web server so that it permanently detects the old URL and redirects users to the new URL.

All URL parameters have remained unchanged apart from **one**, see below;

Old URLs;

```
https://example.com/products/cat_one/record/1656782?lang=eng&type=grey
https://example.com/products/cat_one/record/1188746?lang=eng&type=blue
https://example.com/products/cat_one/record/4499814?lang=eng&type=black
```

New URLs;

```
https://example.com/products/cat/record/1656782?lang=eng&type=grey
https://example.com/products/cat/record/1188746?lang=eng&type=blue
https://example.com/products/cat/record/4499814?lang=eng&type=black
```

As you can see, the `cat_one` parameter has changed to `cat`.

We've been told by the supplier that this kind of redirect isn't possible and it's our responsibility to update all old URLs manually, surely this isn't correct?

How can I achieve this, wither via htaccess, vhosts file, or similar - I've seen various ways to achieve this. I think I require a 301 redirect / rewrite rule?